# Getting data attribute from root in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, attributes, javascript-objects, react-props

I'm trying to grab the attribute listed in the div being rendered but it returns undefined. Any idea on how to go about it will be greatly appreciated

**index.html**

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root" data-username="mark"></div>
  </body>
```

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
if (root) {
  console.log(root.dataset)
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think `ReactDOM.createRoot` returns the HTMLElement. Try `document.getElementById("root").dataset` instead.